# Leetcode : Submitted Function producing Unexpected output

Tags: python, algorithm

When I am submitting the following solution

```
class Solution:
def isSubsequence(self, s: str, t: str) -> bool:
    li = []
    i = 0
    for ch in t:
        if ch == s[i]:
            i+=1
            #debug
            li.append(ch)
    if s == ''.join(li):
        return "true"
    else:
        return "false"
```

in leetcode, solution is failing because it it shows ouput being `true` [as can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3O5N.png). But output for this testcase on my mahcine is `false` which is correct and expected ouput. I have tried finding solution for this on various forums and already tried all the recommened solution provided by [this post](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011834174-I-encountered-Wrong-Answer-Runtime-Error-for-a-specific-test-case-When-I-test-my-code-using-this-test-case-it-produced-the-correct-output-Why-) by leetcode but it is also not working.

The test case for which solution is failing:

`"axc"
"ahbgdc"`

Question can be found [here on leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/is-subsequence/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`False != 'false'`, and every non-empty string (including `'false'`) evaluates to `True`.

Just return `True` and `False` (bool values, like type hints suggest), not strings.

```
def isSubsequence(self, s: str, t: str) -> bool:
    li = []
    i = 0
    for ch in t:
        if ch == s[i]:
            i+=1
            #debug
            li.append(ch)
    if s == ''.join(li):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: In the given examples they have given `return false` that's why I used 'false' and 'true'. Thanks for help

Comment: The given examples are from other languages where boolean values are lowercase. See that they still don't have quotes around them - ergo they're not strings.